# Node Cheerio to scrape an entire site

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, cheerio

Has anybody used Node Cheerio to scrape an entire site and not just the home / first page the scraper gets pointed to?

At the minute I'm doing the following which only scrapes the target page.

```
request('http://arandomsite.com/', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            ...
            ...
            ...
};
```

Comment: It's unclear what data you want to scrape from the site. `request` only returns one page, so you'll need to collect hrefs from the first page and plug those into `request` to explore deeper into the website's link tree.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Cheerio, but I would assume (as with may other scrapers), it will only do the page you point it to. Assuming the cheerio.load returns a jquery like api, you would probably have to do something like

```
$('a').each(function(index, a) {
    //TODO: You may want to keep track here of which you have done, and not redo any.
    request('http://arandomsite.com' + a.attr('href'), myPageProcessFunction);
});
```

Obviously you would need to add things like iframes as well to make sure you get a complete result.

In order to clarify, here is some updated code:

```
request('http://arandomsite.com/', function responseFunction(error, response, html) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('a').each(function(index, a) {
        request('http://arandomsite.com' + a.attr('href'), responseFunction);
    });
};
});
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that the request function is directly below my node dependency variables and so the one problem I can see is that by wrapping the request in `$('a').each(function(index, a) { };` is gonna going to cause $ is undefined.

Comment: I do not mean wrapping the request. This code should be inside the request after $ has been loaded. When I say call request on each link, I mean make a new request call, and pass the current function as the callback result.

Comment: I see your logic and thanks for the updated code, it's making sense. The only problem that I have no is that it's saying that a has no method 'attr'? Here's a link to a pastie with the full code to give you a better understanding of exactly what I'm doing http://pastie.org/private/snykxn92q23ga8srnpak3a#1,7

Comment: I guess its passing the actual anchor element in. You should be able to change to to a.href in that case (instead of a.attr('href'))

Comment: That also hasn't done much. I got this as a response from the developer of cheerio:

"You can build an entire scrapper, by following <a> tags and whatnot and scraping those pages."

Comment: Hmmm... Like I said, I have never used it, but it should be close. The developers response is simply telling you to do what we are working on here. Perhaps, as a last try, you can try $(a).attr('href').

Comment: I've got it working using a.href however it still only seems to track links from the first page and doesn't crawl the entire site... Have you done something similar to this using a different node plugin?